# How to get all roles that a user is a member of (including inherited roles)?

Tags: postgresql, users, role, postgresql-9.3, access-control

Let's say I have two Postgresql database groups, "authors" and "editors", and two users, "maxwell" and "ernest".

```
create role authors;

create role editors;

create user maxwell;

create user ernest;

grant authors to editors; --editors can do what authors can do

grant editors to maxwell; --maxwell is an editor

grant authors to ernest; --ernest is an author
```

I would like to write a performant function that returns a list of the roles (preferably their oid's) that maxwell belongs to, something like this:

```
create or replace function get_all_roles() returns oid[] ...
```

It should return the oids for maxwell, authors, and editors (but not ernest).

But I am not sure how to do it when there is inheritance.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can query the system catalog with a [recursive query](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html), in particular [`pg_auth_members`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-auth-members.html):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT oid FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = 'maxwell'

   UNION ALL
   SELECT m.roleid
   FROM   cte
   JOIN   pg_auth_members m ON m.member = cte.oid
   )
SELECT oid, oid::regrole::text AS rolename FROM cte;  -- oid & name
```

[The manual about the cast to object identifier type `regrole`.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html)

BTW 1: `INHERIT` is the default behavior of [`CREATE ROLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrole.html) and doesn't have to be spelled out.

BTW 2: circular dependencies are not possible. Postgres disallows that. So we don't have to check for that.

Comment: How can I see the role name instead of only the id?

Comment: @david.perez: I added the role name and some explanation above.

Comment: "*`INHERIT` is the default behavior of and doesn't have to be spelled out.*" - don't you still need to check for that in the `JOIN` though?

Comment: Is it possible to go the other way? So instead of getting all parents get all children?

Answer (score 30):

This is a simplified version of [Craig Ringer's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/56104/7119) that a non superuser can use directly:

```
 SELECT oid, rolname FROM pg_roles WHERE
   pg_has_role( 'maxwell', oid, 'member');
```

`pg_roles` is essentially a view on `pg_authid` accessible to public, as it doesn't reveal passwords, contrary to `pg_authid`. The base `oid` is even exported into the view. When not needing passwords, there's no point in creating the dedicated superuser-owned function.

Answer (score 22):

Short version:

```
SELECT a.oid 
FROM pg_authid a 
WHERE pg_has_role('maxwell', a.oid, 'member');
```

Here we use [a version of `pg_has_role` that takes a role name as the subject and role oid to test for membership](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html), passing `member` mode so we test for inherited memberships.

The advantage of using `pg_has_role` is that it uses PostgreSQL's internal caches of role information to satisfy membership queries quickly.

You might want to wrap this in a `SECURITY DEFINER` function, since `pg_authid` has restricted access. Something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION user_role_memberships(text)
RETURNS SETOF oid
LANGUAGE sql
SECURITY DEFINER
SET search_path = pg_catalog, pg_temp
AS $$
SELECT a.oid 
FROM pg_authid a 
WHERE pg_has_role($1, a.oid, 'member');
$$;

REVOKE EXECUTE ON FUNCTION user_role_memberships(text) FROM public;

GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION user_role_memberships(text) TO ...whoever...;
```

You can use `pg_get_userbyid(oid)` to get the role name from the oid without the need to query `pg_authid`:

```
SELECT a.oid AS member_oid, pg_get_userbyid(oid) AS member_name
FROM pg_authid a 
WHERE pg_has_role('maxwell', a.oid, 'member');
```

Comment: +1 anyway, since `pg_has_role()` is probably a bit faster than my recursive query, even if that hardly matters. One last thing though: it returns *all* roles for supersusers, which may or may not be a welcome side effect. That's where the result differs from my query.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my take on it.
It works for one specific user or all users.

```
select a.oid as user_role_id
, a.rolname as user_role_name
, b.roleid as other_role_id
, c.rolname as other_role_name
from pg_roles a
inner join pg_auth_members b on a.oid=b.member
inner join pg_roles c on b.roleid=c.oid 
where a.rolname = 'user_1'
```

Comment: This would be much improved if you explained how if differed from, and improved upon, the previous answers. You can edit the additional information directly into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will do it

```
SELECT 
    oid 
FROM 
    pg_roles 
WHERE 
    oid IN (SELECT 
                roleid 
            FROM 
                pg_auth_members 
            WHERE 
                member=(SELECT oid FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname='maxwell'));
```

If you prefer to get the role names then replace the first `oid` with `rolname`.

Comment: Use oid::regrole::text column to get roles name

Comment: This ignores multi-level inheritance afaict

Answer (score 1):

if you want to know all roles of your currently active role:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.my_roles
AS WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
         SELECT pg_roles.oid,
            pg_roles.rolname
           FROM pg_roles
          WHERE pg_roles.rolname = CURRENT_USER
        UNION ALL
         SELECT m.roleid,
            pgr.rolname
           FROM cte cte_1
             JOIN pg_auth_members m ON m.member = cte_1.oid
             JOIN pg_roles pgr ON pgr.oid = m.roleid
        )
 SELECT array_agg(cte.rolname) AS my_roles
   FROM cte;
```