# How can I list all privileges that a PostgreSQL role has?

Tags: postgresql, permissions

... including the inherited ones? When organizing access rights through different roles, this seems to be something really useful, yet I haven't found anything that would show how to do this.

AIUI, I can use `\dp` to list all the privileges a role has been granted, and I can use `\du` to list all the roles a role is "member of", but I haven't yet come across a command (or query) that would list all the privileges a role has, *including all the inherited privileges* (and from what role a given privilege was inherited).

I can imagine how to combine the queries behind `\du` and `\dp` to recursively get all the "member of" relationships of a given role, then get all the privileges of all the roles in that membership tree, and list them in a useful way. It doesn't look like rocket science, but it's also doesn't look like something trivial that I can do in a couple minutes. I'm just wondering whether this has been done before -- I can't be the first to want this.

The answers in [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4286/list-the-database-privileges-using-psql/184339#184339) show a few ways to query privileges, but nothing about inherited privileges. [This answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/56098/258427) shows a recursive query to get the roles, but doesn't address privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Here is m option to get privileges. Hope someone will find it useful

```
WITH server_permissions AS (
    SELECT 
        r.rolname, 
        'Server_Permissions' AS "Level", 
        r.rolsuper, 
        r.rolinherit,
        r.rolcreaterole, 
        r.rolcreatedb, 
        r.rolcanlogin,
        ARRAY(
            SELECT b.rolname
            FROM pg_catalog.pg_auth_members m
            JOIN pg_catalog.pg_roles b ON m.roleid = b.oid
            WHERE m.member = r.oid
        ) AS memberof,
        r.rolbypassrls
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles r
    WHERE r.rolname !~ '^pg_'
),

db_ownership AS (
    SELECT 
        r.rolname, 
        'DB_Ownership' AS "Level", 
        d.datname
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d, pg_catalog.pg_roles r
    WHERE d.datdba = r.oid
),

schema_permissions AS (
    SELECT
        'Schema Permissions' AS "Level",                
        r.rolname AS role_name,
        nspname AS schema_name,
        pg_catalog.has_schema_privilege(r.rolname, nspname, 'CREATE') AS create_grant,
        pg_catalog.has_schema_privilege(r.rolname, nspname, 'USAGE') AS usage_grant
    FROM pg_namespace pn, pg_catalog.pg_roles r
    WHERE array_to_string(nspacl, ',') LIKE '%' || r.rolname || '%' 
          AND nspowner > 1
),

table_ownership AS (
    SELECT 
        'Table Ownership' AS "Level",
        tableowner, 
        schemaname, 
        tablename
    FROM pg_tables
    GROUP BY tableowner, schemaname, tablename
),

object_permissions AS (
    SELECT  
        'Object Permissions' AS "Level",
        COALESCE(NULLIF(s[1], ''), 'public') AS rolname,
        n.nspname,
        relname, 
        CASE 
            WHEN relkind = 'm' THEN 'Materialized View'
            WHEN relkind = 'p' THEN 'Partitioned Table'
            WHEN relkind = 'S' THEN 'Sequence'
            WHEN relkind = 'I' THEN 'Partitioned Index'
            WHEN relkind = 'v' THEN 'View'
            WHEN relkind = 'i' THEN 'Index'
            WHEN relkind = 'c' THEN 'Composite Type'
            WHEN relkind = 't' THEN 'TOAST table'
            WHEN relkind = 'r' THEN 'Table'
            WHEN relkind = 'f' THEN 'Foreign Table'
        END AS "Object Type",
        s[2] AS privileges
    FROM 
        pg_class c
        JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = relnamespace
        JOIN pg_roles r ON r.oid = relowner,
        UNNEST(COALESCE(relacl::text[], FORMAT('{%s=arwdDxt/%s}', rolname, rolname)::text[])) acl, 
        REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_ARRAY(acl, '=|/') s 
    WHERE relkind <> 'i' AND relkind <> 't'
)   

SELECT 
    "Level", 
    rolname AS "Role", 
    'N/A' AS "Object Name", 
    'N/A' AS "Schema Name", 
    'N/A' AS "DB Name", 
    'N/A' AS "Object Type", 
    'N/A' AS "Privileges", 
    rolsuper::text AS "Is SuperUser", 
    rolinherit::text,
    rolcreaterole::text, 
    rolcreatedb::text, 
    rolcanlogin::text,
    memberof::text,
    rolbypassrls::text 
FROM server_permissions

UNION

SELECT 
    dow."Level", 
    dow.rolname,
    'N/A',  
    'N/A', 
    datname,
    'N/A',
    'N/A',
    'N/A',
    'N/A',
    'N/A',
    'N/A',
    'N/A',
    'N/A',
    'N/A'
FROM db_ownership AS dow 

UNION

SELECT
    "Level", 
    role_name, 
    'N/A', 
    schema_name, 
    'N/A', 
    'N/A',
    CASE 
        WHEN create_grant IS TRUE AND usage_grant IS TRUE THEN 'Usage+Create' 
        WHEN create_grant IS TRUE AND usage_grant IS FALSE THEN 'Create' 
        WHEN create_grant IS FALSE AND usage_grant IS TRUE THEN 'Usage' 
        ELSE 'None' 
    END, 
    'N/A', 
    'N/A', 
    'N/A',
    'N/A',
    'N/A',
    'N/A',
    'N/A'
FROM schema_permissions

UNION

SELECT 
    "Level", 
    tableowner, 
    tablename, 
    schemaname,
    'N/A',
    'N/A',
    'N/A',
    'N/A',
    'N/A',
    'N/A',
    'N/A',
    'N/A',
    'N/A',
    'N/A'
FROM table_ownership

UNION

SELECT 
    "Level", 
    rolname, 
    relname,  
    nspname, 
    'N/A', 
    "Object Type", 
    privileges,
    'N/A',
    'N/A',
    'N/A',
    'N/A',
    'N/A',
    'N/A',
    'N/A'
FROM object_permissions
ORDER BY "Role";
```